# Reference Individual Class Elements with 'this'

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, this, dom-events

If I'm looping through different elements with the same class with `mouseenter` / `mouseout` events and I'm trying to incorporate the 'this' keyword so the JS only triggers on the element I'm hovering over.  I can't get it to work though.

I've stripped out my attempts to use the 'this' keyword to make the code easier to read.  How do I go about having it so that only the element being hovered over has the `mouseenter` and then `mouseout` events applied to it whilst looping through the elements?

I can't use a jQuery solution.

codepen pen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/mMEEBw

Code is below:

JS

```
// declare variable for the CSS class
var menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

//loop through CSS class to change background to red
function myMouseEnter() {
  for (i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
  menuItem[i].style.background = "red";
  }
}

//loop through CSS class to change remove red background
function myMouseLeave() {
  for (i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
  menuItem[i].style.background = "none";
  }
}

//event handler to add function on mouseenter
for (j = 0; j < menuItem.length; j++) {
menuItem[j].addEventListener('mouseenter', myMouseEnter, false)
}

//event handler to add function on mouseout
for (k = 0; k < menuItem.length; k++) { menuItem[k].addEventListener('mouseout', myMouseLeave, false)
}
```

CSS

```
.menu-item {padding: 10px;
font-family: arial;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="unclick--menuitems">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="//google.com">About</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="//google.com">Projects</a</li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="//google.com">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your two functions, all you need to do is refer to `this`. In that context, `this` refers to the `.menu-item` event that you are currently hovering over.

Note that you'll also probably want to attach a handler for the `<a>` tag children, or else whenever you hover over them, the script will think you're **leaving** the `<li>`, and attempt to change the colours.

This can be done by checking the **[toElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974657(v=vs.85).aspx)** and **[relatedTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974881(v=vs.85).aspx)** of the event in question, and then checking whether those are the parent `<li>` element.

All up, your code would look like this:

```js
// declare variable for the CSS class
var menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

// loop through CSS class to change background to red
function myMouseEnter() {
  this.style.background = "red";
}

// loop through CSS class to change remove red background
function myMouseLeave() {
  // prevent the 'mouseout' from affecting the <a> children
  var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
  if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
    return;
  }
  this.style.background = "none";
}

// event handler to add function on mouseenter
for (j = 0; j < menuItem.length; j++) {
  menuItem[j].addEventListener('mouseenter', myMouseEnter, false);
}

// event handler to add function on mouseout
for (k = 0; k < menuItem.length; k++) {
  menuItem[k].addEventListener('mouseout', myMouseLeave, false);
}
```

```css
.menu-item {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<ul class="unclick--menuitems">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="//google.com">About</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="//google.com">Projects</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="//google.com">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that the functions themselves don't have to loop through the menu items again ;)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much that is such a great / informative answer.